# SQL Server: how transactions work

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

In SQL Server, how many transactions will this produce?

```
DECLARE @deleted BIGINT
SET @deleted = 100000
WHILE @deleted = 100000
BEGIN
DELETE TOP(100000) FROM MYTABLE WITH (ROWLOCK)
where Col1 = 7048 and COL2 = 39727 and Col3 = 0
SET @deleted = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
END
```

If I cancel after running this for 10 minutes will it need to roll back?

Would adding a being transaction and end transaction fix this if I don't want it to rollback past one iteration after a cancel?

Would it make any difference if I put it in a stored procedure?

Comment: A stored proc won't make any difference.  And, as currently written, ALL of the deleted rows will be in a single transaction.  You'd need a begin/commit inside your BEGIN/END to limit the transaction scope size, which would affect your ability to roll back.

Comment: Why are you setting the rowlock hint? Where is the clustered index on this table? Does this seem like something that SHOULD take 10 minutes to complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't have the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`, you have implied transactions.  And, each `DELETE` will be a separate transaction.  So, if you cancel the script, it will rollback the current command.  But, all previous `DELETE` steps are already committed.

If you add a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before your code and a `COMMIT` after your code, then you get a single transaction.  If you cancel the query, you leave an open transaction, where there is not commit or rollback.  In this case, you must submit a `ROLLBACK` command to start the rollback process.

Answer (score 2):

It will be an implicit transaction. remember [ACID](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/10/acid-properties-database-interview-question-week-066/)? everything in SQL Server is a transaction either implicit or explicit otherwise you wouldn't be able to guarantee ACID

Answer (score -2):

I believe this will execute under a single transaction (which SQL Server creates for you in this case). You could run Profiler to validate this. Putting it in a stored proc will not make any difference. I might suggest you put a Begin Tran (and corresponding End Tran) for each pass through the loop. One thing this will help prevent is your transaction log getting too large.